# The map $T\longmapsto \|T\|$ is not continuous in the strong operator topology of $\mathscr B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In the context of Strong and Weak operator topologies on $\mathscr B(H)$ there is an statement that says: the map on $\mathscr B(H)$ that $T\longmapsto \|T\|$ is not continuous in the strong operator topology.

Is this statement trivial? Or need some proof?

so thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that $H$ is an infinite-dimensional, separable Hilbert space.

Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Let $$P_n = e_1\otimes e_1 + \ldots e_n\otimes e_n.$$ Then $(P_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of finite-rank projections converging pointwise to the identity. Consequently, $(I-P_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges pointwise to 0, but $\|I-P_n\| = 1$ for each $n$. In particular, $$\|I-P_n\|\not\to \|0\|=0\text{ as }n\to \infty.$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $e_1 \otimes e_1$?

Comment: Okay, think of $H = \ell_2$, then $e_1\otimes e_1$ is just the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $e_1$. More generally, $P_n$ is just the orthogonal projection onto $\mbox{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$.